# Getting every file from directory in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method that, from a given directory, extract every file (also in every subdirectories). I'm using Files.find for this. The problem is that whenever it finds a file that I can't access it stops but I want to continue the research and add to the list the other files.
This is my code

```
public static List<String> search(String dir){
        List<String> listFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            Files.find(Paths.get(dir), Integer.MAX_VALUE, (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isRegularFile())
                    .forEach((file) -> {
                        listFiles.add(file.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                    });
        } catch (UncheckedIOException ue){
            System.out.println("Can't access that directory");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listFiles;
    }
```

How can I change it?

Comment: Move the try catch inside the foreach?

Comment: What about a [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html)?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: If you were to stick with Streams, consider using `List<String> listFiles = Files.find(...).map(File::toAbsolutePath).map(File::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())` instead to fully utilize the Stream API.

Comment: Your would have more control with a traditional loop. This involves disk access, so I don't think that the added efficiency of streams will help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html#filevisitor) interface from Java 8's NIO package. This class offers multiple functions to test directories for accessibility etc before entering them, as well as built-in error handling and an API to control the behaviour of your application.

Your specific problem would require to create some kind of list (E.g. outside of the `FileVisitor`) which you can then fill from inside the method using `Collection::add`

Sadly, Java's Stream API is completely unable to handle exceptions on its own, so any try to solve your problem with `Stream`s would require a lot of unneccessary work, considering that NIO offers the more verbose, but far superior `FileVisitor` solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for something like this for a long time!